# Translate a ImageMagick convert shell script to Python/PIL script

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to translate some shell scripts using the `convert` cmd to python script using PIL.

Here's the original shell script:

```
convert \
    -resize 25% \
    +repage \
    -background white
    -quality 95 \
    -flatten \
    -gravity center \
    -extent 200x200 \
        img_a.png img_b.jpg
```

Here's what I've being able to translate so far:

```
# Paths
img_a_png_filepath = '/foo/bar/img_a.png'
img_a_name = Path(img_a_png_filepath).stem
img_b_name = f'{img_a_name}.jpg'
img_b_jpg_filepath = f'/foo/bar/{img_b_name}'
# Converting to JPEG    
img_a_png = Image.open(img_a_png_filepath)
# -background white
white_bg = Image.new('RGBA',img_a_png.size ,(255, 255, 255, 255))
white_bg.paste(img_a_png, (0, 0), img_a_png)
white_bg = white_bg.convert('RGB')
white_bg.save(img_b_name, 'JPEG')
# -resize 25%
img_b_jpg = Image.open(img_b_jpg_filepath)
img_b_jpg = img_b_jpg.resize((img_b_jpg.size[0]*0.25, img_b_jpg.size[0]*0.25))
img_b_jpg.save(img_b_name, 'JPEG')
```

I guess the original script is trying to crop from the center with the `-gravity center` and `extent 200x200` but I have no clue how to translate both of those options to PIL.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there! You've got the white background, the `-flatten` (using `paste`) and the resizing.

You just need to do the `-extent` from the centre, so...

- get the width, and halve it `int(im.width/2)` and subtract 100 to use as the left edge and add 100 to use as the right edge
- get the height and do the same to get top and bottom
- crop.

If smaller than 200x200 paste onto a 200x200 canvas.

By the way, there's no need to save the images repeatedly as you are currently doing - just carry on processing what you've got.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I understood the math but it's still not clear to me exactly which function(s) I need to call to consume the width and height recalculations and the crop.